# Xcode Instruments problem

Tags: objective-c, xcode, instruments

Now I am facing strange problem with instruments. Build project, launch it on the simulator, and when I want to inspect my project with Instruments(eg - Object Allocations) nothing happens. Instruments.app loads and that's all! When I try manually to load ObjectAlloc.tracetemplate, apparently it loads, but then I cannot choose the target I want to inspect.

Also, when I run Instruments manually, in the view where earlier were tools now is only one tool - called BLANK :(.

I suppose it is happening because I have recently updated Xcode.

Similar problem I have found [Can't run Instruments from Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358874/cant-run-instruments-from-xcode) but there was no explanations of what caused this problem.

Thanks!

**EDIT : The problem resolved by reinstalling Xcode!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT : The problem resolved by reinstalling Xcode!**